# Universal Analytics - utm parameters in collect.gif

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Have the below parameters in collect.gif.  Not sure why utma,utmz and utmht parameters gets passed  in collect.gif.  Could anyone explain about it.

fl:14.0 r0
_utma:183250937.727261133.1403674305.1403674305.1403678301.2
_utmz:183250937.1403678301.2.2.utmcsr=testsrc1|utmccn=testcamp1|utmcmd=testmed1
_utmht:1403679675665
_u:MACCAAQ~
cid:727261133.1403674305

Comment: could anyone help me about the utm parameters in collect.gif request?

Answer (score 2):

_utma, _utmz, and _utmht are part of the ga.js cookie collection that Google Analytics sets up to gather session and traffic information (duration, number of visits, where traffic is coming from, etc).

After the upgrade, analytics.js only uses one cookie to store information, _GA. If you're seeing these parameters in your GET request, that means you still have the old ga.js cookies sitting around. Clear your cookies, and these parameters will disappear from the request.

Google's developer documents has lots of information on their [use of cookies with Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookie-usage) if you care to read about how these cookies used to be used and what the _GA cookie does.